# Who are these first commentators on Bhagavata?

Tags: history, bhagavata-purana

Sridhara Svami's Bhavartha dipika is the oldest full commentary extant now. Before Sridhara, however Madhvacharya commented whose commentary is also extant called Bhagavata Tattparya Nirnaya. It is a brief commentary where he commented only on 1600 verses.

Jiva Goswami mentions two old commentaries on Bhagavata of Chitsukha and Punyaranya in his sandarbhas. Jiva and Sanatan goswamis mention at times 'chitsukha's version reads as...' when there is different reading of a particular verse and explain the meaning with different reading of the verse as well.

Commenting on SB 10.3.44: Jiva mentions

> Chitsukha had reading janyate

Commenting on SB 10.2.16: Jiva says:

> Śrī Citsukha (the Māyāvādī commentator on Bhāgavatam) comments as
>   follows: mana āviveśa pauruṣaṁ dhāmeti sambandha iti

Sridhara also quotes Chitsukha's in his commentary.

Madhvacharya's Bhagavata tattparya nirnaya was a response to Punyaranya's commentary which is advaitic. That's why Madhva primarily interprets advaitic sounding verses of bhagavata and he comments on 10th and 11th Canto which tend to verge on monism. Other cantos are cursorily treated by Madhva.

Both the commentaries of Chitsukha and Punyaranya are not extant now. Who are these commentators Chitsukha and Punyaranya? Which century did they live?